# Callback function does not work with custom key

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to make custom keypad

```
class KeyboardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const KeyboardButton({required this.buttonChild, this.onPress});
  final Function? onPress;
  final Widget buttonChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onPress,
      child: Container(child: buttonChild),
    );
  }
}
```

usage of it

```
KeyboardButton(
  onPress: () => print('1'), // this doesn't work
  buttonChild: Column(...),
)
```

For some reason the callback doesn't work out. How to fix it?

Comment: `onTap: onPress,`

Comment: @pskink Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

Comment: so define `onPress` the same way [onTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTap.html) is defined - it can be `GestureTapCallback?` or `void Function?`

Comment: @pskink that works, but there is a differnce - onTap is defined as `GestureTapCallback` but IDE shows `Type: void Function()?` on `onTap`

Comment: Please try without arrow function. Use curly braces to call function that have parameter.

Comment: @pskink I said `it works` i.e. after the type changed it works, but what is the reason in types difference?

Comment: ok i see it now: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTap.html - it shows: `GestureTapCallback? onTap` and click on `GestureTapCallback`

Comment: @pskink anyway it solved, thanks

Comment: basically `GestureTapCallback` is defined as: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html - i mean `typedef GestureTapCallback = void Function();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I see missing here.

One is `final void Function()? onPress;`. Since earlier the return type was not acurately specified.

Seccond is `onTap: onPress`. Since earlier your were just returning your function variable and not `calling` your `onPress` function. This can also be written as `onTap: () => onPress?.call()`